# How to know if it is either a positive/negative number or it is referring to a number in binary?

Tags: binary, computer-science

I'm learning Integer data formats in a computer science book and as far as I understand that binary representation of a integer whether it is positive or negative is to have the leftmost bit (msb) be either a 0 for positive or 1 for negative, lets say in a 8-bit computer how would I know if it is talking about 10000010 - 130 in base 10 or if it is referring to negative 2?
I might be wrong, if i'm please correct me.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to just see the string `10000010` somewhere, I don't know... written on a wall or something, how would you know how to interpret it?

You might say, hey, that's ten million and ten ( you thought it was base 10 ) or you might say hey, that's -126 ( you thought it was two's complement binary ), or you might say that's positive 130 ( you thought it was standard binary ).

It is, in a theoretical sense, up to whatever is doing the interpreting how it is interpreted.

So, when a computer is holding 8 bits of data, it's up to it how it interprets it.

Now if you're programming, you can *tell* the computer how you want something interpreted. For example, in c++

```
// char is 1 byte
unsigned char x = 130u;
```

Here I have told the compiler to put 130 **unsigned** into a byte, so the computer will store `10000010` and will interpret it as the value 130

Now consider

```
// char is 1 byte
char x = -126;
```

Here I have told the compiler to put -126 **signed** into a byte, so the computer will again store `10000010` but this time it will interpret it as the value -126.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the answer posted to this question: [Negative numbers are stored as 2's complement in memory, how does the CPU know if it's negative or positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681024/negative-numbers-are-stored-as-2s-complement-in-memory-how-does-the-cpu-know-i?rq=1)

The CPU uses something called an opcode in order to determine which function it will take when manipulating a memory location (in this case, the value 10000010). It is that function within the CPU that will either manipulate it as a negative or a positive number. The CPU doesn't have access to whether or not the number is signed or unsigned - it uses the op code when manipulating that number to determine whether or not it should be a signed or unsigned operation.